# ¿Cómo convierto el timestamp a una fecha en un dataframe de pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con el precio de una acción P y un timestamp que quiero convertir en una fecha.

```
    P       timestamp
0   152.20  1389909600000
1   149.00  1390514400000
2   148.05  1391119200000
```

Entonces ¿Cómo convierto el timestamp a una fecha en un dataframe de pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función `pandas.to_datetime()` puede hacerlo. No obstante es necesario que le especifiques en qué unidades está tu timestamp y cuál es el origen de tiempos.

Por defecto para este último usa el *epoch Unix*, 1 de enero de 1970, pero como unidad por defecto utiliza el nanosegundo. Si este fuera el caso en tus datos, los timestamps que muestras de ejemplo corresponderían al final del día de ese 1 de enero de 1970, por lo que no creo que tus datos estén en nanosegundos.

Un timestamp Unix suele estar habitualmente en segundos. Pero los datos que muestras no pueden ser tampoco segundos ya que en ese caso se trataría de una fecha muy lejana en el futuro (de hecho, se salen de rango para el tipo `datetime`)

Quizás sean milisegundos, en cuyo caso corresponderían a instantes del 16, 23 y 30 de enero de 2014. O microsegundos, en cuyo caso corresponderían a instantes del 17 de enero de 1970.

Sea como sea, la conversión la realizarías así (uso en este ejemplo unidades de milisegundos, que es la hipótesis más razonable ya que en ese caso los instantes corresponden a la misma hora en diferentes días):

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, unit="ms")
```

El nuevo dataframe sería:

```
        P      timestamp                date
0  152.20  1389909600000 2014-01-16 22:00:00
1  149.00  1390514400000 2014-01-23 22:00:00
2  148.05  1391119200000 2014-01-30 22:00:00
```