# ¿Cómo convertir un timestamp en una fecha?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp

Intenté recuperar los precios del stock de Gucci. Utilisé el API msn sobre cinco años. Sin embargo tengo problemas con el timestamp.

```
url = 'https://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=160.1.KER.PAR&chartType=5y'
resp = requests.get(url=url)
prices_gucci = resp.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(prices_gucci[0]['Chart']['Series'])
```

Y obtengo :

```
    IsStitched  P   T
0   NaN         149.00  7397280
1   NaN         148.05  10080
2   NaN         147.50  20160
...
```

Entonces intenté, siguiendo [la respuesta de abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230205/c%C3%B3mo-convierto-el-timestamp-a-una-fecha-en-un-dataframe-de-pandas) :

```
df['T'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'], unit='ms')
```

Pero obtengo :

```
    IsStitched  P   T
0   NaN 149.00  1970-01-01 02:03:17.280
1   NaN 148.05  1970-01-01 00:00:10.080
2   NaN 147.50  1970-01-01 00:00:20.160
...
262 NaN 410.00  1970-01-01 00:43:46.560
263 True    417.10  1970-01-01 00:43:50.175
```

Y no es la fecha. En efecto cuando lo hizo llamando por

```
with open(r"C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Tests\StockPredictions\160.1.KER.PAR.json") as f:
    prices_gucci = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(prices_gucci['5y']['Chart']['Series']), orient='columns')
df = df[["P","timestamp"]]
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
df.head()

    P   timestamp
0   152.20  2014-01-16 22:00:00
1   149.00  2014-01-23 22:00:00
...
```

#### Actualización

Parece que el valor la primera línea de `df['T']`: `7397280`es la diferencia en segundos desde `2000-01-01`, y las otras las diferencias con este primera diferencia.

Comment: ¿Esta pregunta no es lo mismo que [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/230205/7123) ?

Comment: @abulafia Si pero el timestamp parece ser diferente

Comment: Quizás el timestamp usa como unidad "s" en este caso, pues el primer número es pequeño. O quizás es un "timedelta" (distancia entre tiempos), de modo que cada nueva fila indica cuánto tiempo pasó desde la anterior Hace falta esta información para decidir cómo convertirlo a fecha

Comment: @abulafia Según un amigo que trabaja sobre las APIs de MSN, parece que el valor la primera línea de `df['T']`: `7397280` es para `2000-01-01` y los demás son el tiempo desde esta fecha.

Comment: Disculpe, `7397280` es la diferencia en segundos desde `2000-01-01` y las otras las diferencias con este primera diferencia

Comment: diferencia en minutas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.datetime()` es bastante flexible, pues permite que se le pase como parámetro las unidades del timestamp (minutos en este caso) y el origen de tiempos (2000-01-01 en este caso), pero necesita que todos los timestamp tengan el mismo origen de tiempos, lo que no es el caso en este dataframe.

La primera fila del dataframe usa como origen de tiempos 2000-01-01, pero las restantes filas usan como origen el dictado por la primera fila.

La forma más simple que se me ocurre para abordar este problema consiste en sumar a todas las filas salvo la primera, el valor de la primera fila. De este modo ya todas usarán como origen 2000-01-01.

Es decir:

```
# Lectura de datos
url = 'https://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=160.1.KER.PAR&chartType=5y'
resp = requests.get(url=url)
prices_gucci = resp.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(prices_gucci[0]['Chart']['Series'])

# Corregir origen de timestamps
origen = df.loc[0, "T"]
df.loc[1:, "T"] = df.loc[1:, "T"] + origen

# Convertir a datetime
df["fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(df["T"], unit="m", origin=pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01'))

print(df.head())
```

```
  IsStitched       P        T      fecha
0        NaN  149.00  7397280 2014-01-24
1        NaN  148.05  7407360 2014-01-31
2        NaN  147.50  7417440 2014-02-07
3        NaN  152.30  7427520 2014-02-14
4        NaN  151.45  7437600 2014-02-21
```

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia ! Sin embargo, parece que la diferencia es en minutas pero nunca he visto esta unidad.

Comment: @ThePassenger Cuál es en minutos? Las diferencias entre cada fila  y la primera? O la primera también es el número de minutos desde 2000-01-01?

Comment: Si las diferencias entre cada fila y la primera y el número de minutos desde 2000-01-01

Comment: En ese caso la solución es la misma, pero usando `"m"` como unidad. He actualizado la respuesta

Comment: Grr, ya lo intenté y obtenía `OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 'm'` con `df["fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(df["T"], unit="m", origin=pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01'))`

Comment: @ThePassenger Tiene pinta de que en algún momento de tu dataframe la columna T tiene un valor muy alto, que al ser tratado como un timestamp en minutos da como resultado una fecha fuera de rango. Quizás las unidades de esa columna no son consistentes y hay partes en que son segundos en lugar de minutos... pero yo he probado sobre la URL que has dado y he tenido problemas

Comment: O a lo mejor lo habías intentado sobre un dataframe resultado de concatenar varios, y por tanto al inicio de cada nueva "serie" la columna T contenía un nuevo origen de tiempos. Mi solución asume que eso solo ocurre en la fila 0. Si era esta la causa, debes aplicar mi solución a cada "serie" individual, antes de concatenar los resultados.